# This is from thinking in C. I do not see how the variable values are retained

Tags: c

This code asks for 3 integers, determines odd/even, adds evens & evens, odds & odds, this is the entire program, it shares with nothing else and other than what I see as inexplicable behavior, it does precisely what it's supposed to.

The scanf is obviously getting a value from stdio, but it uses 3 different values, does not forget them and spits out the correct answer, and I don't know why, I'll gladly sacrifice my ex-wife for an answer.

```
/* lab3.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int osum = 0;
    int esum = 0;
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        esum += n;
    else
        osum += n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        esum += n;
    else
        osum += n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        esum += n;
    else
        osum += n;

    printf("Sum of evens: %d\n", esum);
    printf("Sum of odds: %d\n", osum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` put the values into `n`. The values are assigned to `esum` and `osum` in the statements `esum += n` and `osum += n`. Do you understand what the `+=` operator does? (And thanks, but I already have a wife and don't want your ex- :-).

Comment: If you think it doesn't forget the three values, print them again after the sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's add comments to each line:

```
int main() {
  int osum = 0;  /* defines variable osum and initializes it to zero */
  int esum = 0;  /* defines variable esum and initializes it to zero */
  int n;         /* defines variable n */

  printf("Before starting, esum=%d, osum=%d\n", esum, osum);

  scanf("%d", &n);  /* reads an integer from stdin, assigns the value to n */
  if (n % 2 == 0)   /* if n is evenly divisible by 2.... */
    esum += n;      /* then n is added to esum, assigning the result to esum */
  else              /* otherwise n is not evenly divisible by 2... */
    osum += n;      /* so n is added to osum, assigning the result to osum */

  printf("After first read, esum=%d, osum=%d\n", esum, osum);

  scanf("%d", &n);  /* same as above */
  if (n % 2 == 0)   /*  "   "    "   */
    esum += n;      /*  "   "    "   */
  else              /*  "   "    "   */
    osum += n;      /*  "   "    "   */

  printf("After second read, esum=%d, osum=%d\n", esum, osum);

  scanf("%d", &n);  /*  "   "    "   */
  if (n % 2 == 0)   /*  "   "    "   */
    esum += n;      /*  "   "    "   */
  else              /*  "   "    "   */
    osum += n;      /*  "   "    "   */

  printf("Sum of evens: %d\n", esum);  /* prints esum */
  printf("Sum of odds: %d\n", osum);   /* prints osum */
  return 0;                            /* returns value of zero from main */
}
```

Does that help make it clearer?

### EDIT

I took @ElliotFrisch's idea and added printfs after each read-and-assign section to show how the values change. Thanks, Elliot!

Comment: If I read this correctly, the program does the first loop and printf, and only then, proceeds to the second loop, that's what I wasn't seeing, I thought it was doing #1, #2,#3 printf. Thank You.